# Placing 2 data series side by side using bar() of pyplot - Left Argument

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, bar-chart

I'm plotting 2 data series side by side using bar(), most of the plotting points on one axis are the same in terms of the 'left' parameter of bar(), in order to shift the 2nd data series, I'm adding a bit of space to the starting points, but the addition is causing this error:

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple

Below is my snippet:

```
width = 0.5
genGraph, xyParts = p.subplots() 
xPart = xyParts.bar(fFreqs, fVals, width, color='#758085')
yPart = xyParts.bar((oFreqs + width,), oVals, width, color='#C9FABE')
```

fFreqs and oFreqs are tuples and they serve as arguments for the 'left' parameter, 'width' is an offset to shift the starting point of oFreqs (the 2nd data set).  I've tried a simple concatenation by adding 'oFreqs' to 'width' without parentheses and extra comma.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `oFreqs` is a tuple, this

```
(oFreqs + width,)
```

will not do what you think it should. Adding two tuples just concatenates them. If you want to add a constant to all parts of a tuple, you should be using `numpy` arrays (because you have `numpy` available as you are using `matplotlib`. Try:

```
import numpy as np

...

yPart = xyParts.bar(np.array(oFreqs) + width, ...)
```

This converts the tuple into an array, and then the addition does what one would think.